# JavaScript object creation

Tags: javascript, object, helper

JavaScript newbie here, I was going through some js code at work when i came across a helper function for object creation, which went like this

```
createElement = function(name, data){
    if(name == TYPES.TEXT){
    return new Text(data);
    }
    else if(name == TYPES.WORD){
    return new Word(data);
    }
    else if(name == TYPES.PARAGRAPH){
    return new Paragraph(data); 
    }
    else if(name == TYPES.TABLE){
    return new Table(data);
    }
    <list goes on and on and on... >
}
```

while this does get the job done i would like to know if there is a better, cleaner way of writing this.

Comment: You might be interested in the [switch structure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're right, excessive `if..then` or `switch` logic is a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) and can almost always be refactored into something more elegant. In this case, a factory based upon a name can be refactored into a dictionary with key as that name and value as the function to return

```
var dictionary = {};
dictionary[TYPES.TEXT] = Text;
dictionary[TYPES.WORD] = Word;
dictionary[TYPES.PARAGRAPH] = Paragraph;
dictionary[TYPES.TABLE] = Table;

createElement = function(name, data){
    return new dictionary[name](data);
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/KkMnd/

**EDIT:** That line in the `createElement` method could/should first check that something is configured for the `TYPES.*` passed in. A good way is to check that there is an element in the dictionary before trying to call that method.

```
return (typeof dictionary[name] == 'function') ? new dictionary[name](data) : some_default_value;
```

Comment: +1 And the extra good thing about this solution is that if your `TYPES` needs to be expanded, you don't have to change any *logic* to do so, which you would have to do with a `switch`.

Comment: +1 for simplifying and for mentioning the name of this pattern (a factory pattern). What concerns me is that OP did not mention the last "_else_" statement and you should implement it here as well, eg. `return (typeof dictionary[name] != 'undefined') ? dictionary[name](data) : something_goes_here;` (just replace `something_goes_here` with the expected result if nothing found).

Comment: @Tadeck - I think thats a very good suggestion, however i'm not going to edit it into the answer for 2 reasons. a) His `name` argument appears to be a pseudo-enum sort of object. Im assuming that these are safe enough that nobody would pass a random string in. b) It complicates the solution enough to make it confusing. However for the OP's sake... you might well want to put that check into your real code.

Comment: Thanks jamiec. Using the dictionary looks cleaner. @Tadeck is suppose the last else can be captured this way..  return dictionary[name] || default_case

Comment: @Tadeck sorry.. dint know the enter key would submit the comment. i just wanted to make sure is this is a good way of handling the default case return dictionary[name](data) || default_object

Comment: @karthik - no, do it the way suggested above. I'll edit it into the answer in case its hard to read in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a bit cleaner but semantically the same to use a switch statement.

```
function createElement(name,data){
switch(name)
{
case TYPES.TEXT:
  return new Text(data)
  break;
case TYPES.WORD:
  return new WORD(data)
  break;
default:
  // etc. code to be executed if no values match
}
}
```